# pstricks in MacTeX

Tags: errors, pstricks, mactex

I got a new Mac with OS X 10.8.3 and installed MacTeX-2012, but pstricks doesn't seem to work now.  Before I used (plain) TeX and chose the TeX and DVI typesetting option.  When I looked for help in various FAQs and mailing lists, the answers I found were specific to LaTeX, though.  So I downloaded a pstricks example file from TUG that uses LaTeX, and that doesn't work either.  Even after I put

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
```

at the top of the file and ran it with LaTeX or XeLaTeX, it wouldn't work.  For example, with the LaTeX engine (and TeX and DVI typesetting), I get this error message:

```
### This is /usr/texbin/simpdftex, Version 20070809
### /usr/texbin/latex hilbert.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./hilbert.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(./pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v0.05  <2010/01/17> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(./hilbert.aux)
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--44
[][] 
[1] (./hilbert.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on hilbert.dvi (1 page, 507508 bytes).
SyncTeX written on hilbert.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on hilbert.log.

### /usr/texbin/dvips -R -Poutline  -o /tmp/altpdflatex.55576-1370136084/hilbert.ps hilbert.dvi

This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2013.06.01:2121' -> /tmp/altpdflatex.55576-1370136084/hilbert.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
[1] 

### ps2pdf13 /tmp/altpdflatex.55576-1370136084/hilbert.ps /tmp/altpdflatex.55576-1370136084/hilbert.pdf
/usr/texbin/simpdftex: line 495: ps2pdf13: command not found

### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.55576-1370136084/hilbert.pdf ()
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that you didn't install properly Ghostscript. Did you choose a custom installation for MacTeX?

Comment: The issue is related to the unknown executable `ps2pdf13`. Use `ps2pdf` instead. How to setup `simpdftex` is explained on the main page: http://man.he.net/man1/simpdftex -- However if you are interested in an automatic compilation tool you can have a look at `arara`.

Comment: No, I did the standard installation of MacTeX.

Comment: `ps2pdf13` should exist in a standard MacTeX installation. What does `which ps2pdf ps2pdf13` (type from the Terminal) return for you?

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Under Typesetting in TeXShop I don't see any option for Ghostscript.  Does this mean it's not installed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed now. After installing Ghostscript 9.07, it works fine when I chose "TeX and DVI" under Typesetting. Thanks for your suggestions everyone!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but Ghostscript is part of the standard MacTeX install, so it's odd that it wasn't installed for you. Here's an image of the default installer configuration: [MacTeX installer image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VItoA.png).

Comment: I just noticed that. Ghostscript 9.05 is in MacTeX, but installing Ghostscript 9.07 seemed to fix the problem for me.